# Why virtual inherit 2 classes raises object size?

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, model, virtual

I've got a simple object, compile and run under 64bit ubuntu1804 with g++:

```
struct Base1{ int mi,mj,mk,mh;};
struct Base2{ int ni,nj,nk,nh;};

struct Child1:virtual Base1{virtual void f(){}};
struct Child2:virtual Base1{virtual void f(){}};
struct Derive1:Child1,Child2{};

struct Child3:virtual Base2{virtual void f(){}};
struct Child4:virtual Base2{virtual void f(){}};
struct Derive2:Child3,Child4{};

struct Final:Derive1,Derive2{};
int main(){
        cout<<"C1="<<sizeof(Child1)<<endl;
        cout<<"C2="<<sizeof(Child2)<<endl;
        cout<<"C3="<<sizeof(Child3)<<endl;
        cout<<"C4="<<sizeof(Child4)<<endl;
        cout<<"D1="<<sizeof(Derive1)<<endl;
        cout<<"D2="<<sizeof(Derive2)<<endl;
        cout<<"F ="<<sizeof(Final)<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The program outputs:

```
$ g++ om.cpp -O2 && ./a.out
C1=24
C2=24
C3=24
C4=24
D1=32
D2=32
F =64
```

I know that sizeof(B1) is 16, and Child1-Child4 as adding virtual function(vptr pointing to vtable) will add an extra pointer size, so they're of size 24, no problem. But why sizeof Derive1/Derive2 are 32?
The c++ object model adds an extra pointer to it, right? But what doesn this extra pointer actually do, and why it's necessary to add this extra 8byte pointer? I don't see any necessity here.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it adds two pointers to `Base1` or `Base2` subobjects that are inherited virtually.

Comment: This depends on the abi: example [Itanium C++ abi](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#vtable). According to this abi, the types would have the same size as you observed. D1 layout would be `D1{ C1{vtable_ptr:8bytes};C2{vtable_ptr:8bytes};Base1:16bytes}}`

Comment: Think about it - you can cast a pointer to the derived object to any base class and you should have a valid vtable pointer at first bytes. So it's quite logical to have one vtable per each base class in case of multiple inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plausible layout:

```
Final
----------------------
| Derive1
| --------------------
| | Child1
| | ------------------
| | | Pointer to Base1 (8 bytes)
| | ------------------
| | Child2
| | ------------------
| | | Pointer to Base1 (8 bytes)
| | ------------------
| --------------------
| Derive2
| --------------------
| | Child3
| | ------------------
| | | Pointer to Base2 (8 bytes)
| | ------------------
| | Child4
| | ------------------
| | | Pointer to Base2 (8 bytes)
| | ------------------
| --------------------
| Base1
| --------------------
| | mi                 (4 bytes)
| | mj                 (4 bytes)
| | mk                 (4 bytes)
| | mh                 (4 bytes)
| --------------------
| Base2
| --------------------
| | ni                 (4 bytes)
| | nj                 (4 bytes)
| | nk                 (4 bytes)
| | nh                 (4 bytes)
| --------------------
----------------------
```

Total size: 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 64
Note that this size could grow to accommodate vtable pointers if your virtual functions were less trivial and/or actually overrode something. (As it stands, the virtual functions can be optimized completely away.)

To understand why all these pointers are necessary, consider the following:

```
Final foo;
Child3 * c3 = &foo;
Child4 * c4 = &foo;
Base2 * b23 = c3;
Base2 * b24 = c4;
```

If you were given `c4`, how would you convert it to a pointer to `Base2`? Keep in mind that you are not allowed to assume that `c4` points to part of `Final`; your solution must also work for the following, and it must be equally applicable to `c3`.

```
Child4 c4;
Base2 * b24 = &c4;
```